# Using otf-libertinus with ConTeXt for typesetting math

Tags: fonts, context, math-fonts

I'm trying to use [Libertinus Serif](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/otf-libertinus) font for typesetting both text and math.

```
\starttypescript [libertinusserif]
\setups[font:fallback:serif]          % security: if not found==> back to defaults
% \definefontsynonym[ConTeXt basics name] [Human readable]       [features=default]
  \definefontsynonym[Serif]                 [LibertinusSerif-Regular]       [features=default]
  \definefontsynonym[SerifItalic]           [LibertinusSerif-Italic]        [features=default]
  \definefontsynonym[SerifBold]             [LibertinusSerif-Semiold]           [features=default]
  \definefontsynonym[SerifBoldItalic]       [LibertinusSerif-SemiboldItalic]    [features=default]
\stoptypescript

\starttypescript [libertinusserif]
  \definetypeface [libertinusserif]    [rm] [serif] [libertinusserif]    [default]
\stoptypescript

\setupbodyfont[libertinusserif, 14pt]

\starttext
Just some text.

Some text with \m{m+a_{th}} in it.

\stoptext
```

and it drops out with the following error:

```
Math error: parameter \Umathsub_shift_down\textstyle is not set


\m_syst_action_nop ...artimath #1\normalstopimath 
                                                  \fi 
l.21 Some text with \m{m+a_{th}}
                               in it.
```

(Note: when I comment out the line with math or do not set the body font, the output is produced.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think one problem (the error you get) is that you do not define a math font.

If you use the standalone version, you just have to be sure to have the fonts on your system where it can be found (my `$OSFONTDIR` is set to `$HOME/.fonts`). It seems that this is not your problem, since you get the fonts when you comment out the math.

Thus, you will have these nice fonts working by adding

```
\setupbodyfont[libertinus]
```

to your setup. The definitions seems to be taken from

```
tex/texmf-context/tex/context/fonts/mkiv/type-imp-libertinus.mkiv
```

Comment: Oh, somehow I overlooked that there's a predefined definition. I'm ready to mark the answer as accepted.